# iOS PDF's Path keeps on changing every time

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am working on a project where I am supposed to take one pdf and add it to my list in the table view and processed it. Now again when user is selecting that pdf from list i need to process it again but its not opening. When i investigated the issue i got different path each and every time for the same PDF.

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    pdfURL = url
    print("PDF URL : \(url)")
    pdfDetailFilling()}
```

Any work around for opening same pdf with one URL
Here are 2 different url i got,

> file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/278B32A4-3F13-4A20-AA11-A1B1D3501572/tmp/in.gingermind.eyed-Inbox/cprogramming_tutorial.pdf
>
> file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5F05E527-BF15-43D1-9DBC-FF89BE772898/tmp/in.gingermind.eyed-Inbox/cprogramming_tutorial.pdf

Comment: That's a feature. Don't store absolute paths.

Comment: @Gereon what path I should store then.

Answer (score 2):

Don't store absolute paths. Only store the part that's relative to e.g. `NSTemporaryDirectory()` or one of the directories you get from `FileManager.default.url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)`

Comment: I am still getting the same results just the /temp/ change to /document/ that's it and the 5F05E527-BF15-43D1-9DBC-FF89BE772898 AKA app-ID keeps on changing every time app launch so do you have any idea to get one path and keep is constant for all sessions.

Comment: Are you sure this is a relative path? From your example above, you should only store "in.gingermind.eyed-Inbox/cprogramming_tutorial.pdf" as that's the part relative to the tmp directory.